# Uniform Resource Identifier validation using python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am pretty new to flask, i wonder how to properly validate a Uniform Resource Identifier in flask.

```
email = EmailField('Email Address', validators=[DataRequired()])
#this is not enough validation for url
url = EmailField('Uniform Resource Identifier', validators=[DataRequired()])
password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like `DataRequired` and `Email` are builtin validators, there is a builtin [`URL` validator](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#wtforms.validators.URL) for FlaskWTForms.

```
url = StringField('Uniform Resource Identifier', validators=[URL()]
```